# issues fetching href links from amazon website. xpath find many more href links than expected.

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to collect all the urls for each video from the amazon website below.

```
https://www.amazon.com/video-Prime/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A2858778011%2Ck%3Avideo
```

I'm using scrapy shell to interactively test my code.
I started scrapy shell like below. I

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Dinstant-video&field-keywords=video&rh=n%3A2858778011%2Ck%3Avideo'
```

My response status is 200. Then in scrapy shell,  I tried to extract all the video url using xpath selector like below:

```
response.xpath("//ul[contains(@id, 's-results-list-atf')]/li//a/@href").extract()
```

I got way more href link than expected. When I checked the web html, that does not make sense. There are ten videos on that page and only one href link for each video. I cannot understand why that happens.  I appreciate it if anyone can help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below XPath to match only required links

```
//ul[@id="s-results-list-atf"]//a[h2]/@href
```

Answer (score 0):

> There are ten videos on that page and only one href link for each video.

Are you sure you're looking at the correct page?
Here's a screenshot of the first result I see on that page, with borders added around links.

[image: Arrival]

As you can see, there are 9 links in total for this particular item.

Looks like you'll have to make your xpath more specific, so it only captures the links you want.

Comment: thanks. I see. you are right.  let me try to make it specific.